# Show/Hide Views based on image selected on first div in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement like i have to display first popup with all 5 images.
When user click on any image it will hit the action method in controller with ID1 and ID2 parameters and come up with partial view .On new partial view first div with image will be hidden.Can i show div2 with all the details in the same page?

```html
//Div with images
<div1>
<img1>
<img2>
<img3>
<img4>
<img5>
</div>

// div with partial view
<div2>
....
</div>
```

```
public ActionMethod Esimate(int ID1, int ID2)
      { return Partial View("Some Other View")};
```

Comment: Yes you can. On any image click, perform ajax call, get the response with html partial view and append the response html where ever you want on page, did you get it? Or show us what have you done so far to achieve this?

Comment: @TejasVaishnav Thanks i have used ajax

Comment: Great, good know that it helped you. Happy coding!